# Как сделать так, чтобы бот ставил реакцию на свое сообщение?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Можете показать, на этом примере, пожалуйста

```
@commands.command(name='play', description=config.HELP_YT_LONG, help=config.HELP_YT_SHORT, aliases=['p', 'yt', 'pl'])
async def _play_song(self, ctx, *, track: str):

    current_guild = utils.get_guild(self.bot, ctx.message)
    audiocontroller = utils.guild_to_audiocontroller[current_guild]

    if(await utils.is_connected(ctx) == None):
        if await audiocontroller.uconnect(ctx) == False:
            return

    if track.isspace() or not track:
        return

    if await utils.play_check(ctx) == False:
        return

    # reset timer
    audiocontroller.timer.cancel()
    audiocontroller.timer = utils.Timer(audiocontroller.timeout_handler)

    if audiocontroller.playlist.loop == True:
        await ctx.send("Повтор включен! Используйте {}loop, чтобы отключить".format(config.BOT_PREFIX))
        return

    song = await audiocontroller.process_song(track)

    if song is None:
        await ctx.send(config.SONGINFO_ERROR)
        return

    if song.origin == linkutils.Origins.Default:

        if audiocontroller.current_song != None and len(audiocontroller.playlist.playque) == 0:
            await ctx.send(embed=song.info.format_output(config.SONGINFO_NOW_PLAYING))
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed=song.info.format_output(config.SONGINFO_QUEUE_ADDED))


    elif song.origin == linkutils.Origins.Playlist:
        await ctx.send(config.SONGINFO_PLAYLIST_QUEUED)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@commands.command():
async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✔️')
```

Если хотите сделать плеер, то лучше использовать `lavalink`